# Selecting rows in pandas for where a column is equal to certain values

Tags: python, pandas, selection

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image: Pandas dataframe]

From this, I want to grab all the rows for particular Filters (1st column). So for example, I want to grab the rows for F218W, F336W, and F373N.

What is the easiest way to do this in pandas?

In addition if I wanted to grab the rows for those filters but also only for Chip 1, how could I do that easily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple slicing:

```
df[df["# Filter"].isin(["F218W", "F336W","F373N"])]
```

If the rules across multiple columns, you can simply combine them using `&`:

```
df[df["# Filter"].isin(["F218W", "F336W","F373N"]) & (df["Chip"] == 1)]
```